# Custom fields in WooCommerce product variations

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields

**QUESTION UPDATED AS PEOPLE SEEMED TO MISUNDERSTAND IT:**

Using the WooCommerce plugin for WordPress, I'd like to display the product variation names in the Additional Information tab in the same way as weight and dimesions are displayed.

For instance, I have a product that comes in two sizes, 2 litres and 10 litres, therefore it's a variable product with the two product variations '2 litres' and '10 litres'. If I check the box 'display on product page', size is displayed in the Additional Information tab like this: 'Size: 2 litres, 10 litres'.
I want it to work like the weight and dimensions, so when the product variation '2 litres' is selected, the Additional Information tab will display 'Size: 2 litres', and when the product variation '10 litres' is selected, the Additional Information tab will display 'Size: 10 litres'.

Can this be done?

Comment: I don't think you need custom fields. It sounds like you need to create another attribute for "size" and create additional variations based on that new attribute.

Comment: I did that. But the Additional Information tab says 'Size: 2 litres, 10 litres' regardless what variation is selected. I need it to say 'Size: 2 litres' when the 2 litres variation is selected, and 'Size: 10 litres' when the 10 litres variation is selected. THAT'S my problem.

Comment: That's a different question that what you've described above. Can you edit your question?

Comment: I believe it's excactly the same question, but sure, I'll update the question to be more specific about it.

Comment: Question updated now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the full code to add all types of custom input fields for Product Variations:

```
<?php
// Add Variation Settings
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_after_variable_attributes','variation_settings_fields', 10, 3 );
// Save Variation Settings
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'save_variation_settings_fields', 10, 2 );
/**
 * Create new fields for variations
 *
*/
function variation_settings_fields( $loop, $variation_data, $variation ) {
    // Text Field
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( 
        array( 
            'id'          => '_text_field[' . $variation->ID . ']', 
            'label'       => __( 'My Text Field', 'woocommerce' ), 
            'placeholder' => 'http://',
            'desc_tip'    => 'true',
            'description' => __( 'Enter the custom value here.', 'woocommerce' ),
            'value'       => get_post_meta( $variation->ID, '_text_field', true )
        )
    );
    // Number Field
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( 
        array( 
            'id'          => '_number_field[' . $variation->ID . ']', 
            'label'       => __( 'My Number Field', 'woocommerce' ), 
            'desc_tip'    => 'true',
            'description' => __( 'Enter the custom number here.', 'woocommerce' ),
            'value'       => get_post_meta( $variation->ID, '_number_field', true ),
            'custom_attributes' => array(
                            'step'  => 'any',
                            'min'   => '0'
                        ) 
        )
    );
    // Textarea
    woocommerce_wp_textarea_input( 
        array( 
            'id'          => '_textarea[' . $variation->ID . ']', 
            'label'       => __( 'My Textarea', 'woocommerce' ), 
            'placeholder' => '', 
            'description' => __( 'Enter the custom value here.', 'woocommerce' ),
            'value'       => get_post_meta( $variation->ID, '_textarea', true ),
        )
    );
    // Select
    woocommerce_wp_select( 
    array( 
        'id'          => '_select[' . $variation->ID . ']', 
        'label'       => __( 'My Select Field', 'woocommerce' ), 
        'description' => __( 'Choose a value.', 'woocommerce' ),
        'value'       => get_post_meta( $variation->ID, '_select', true ),
        'options' => array(
            'one'   => __( 'Option 1', 'woocommerce' ),
            'two'   => __( 'Option 2', 'woocommerce' ),
            'three' => __( 'Option 3', 'woocommerce' )
            )
        )
    );
    // Checkbox
    woocommerce_wp_checkbox( 
    array( 
        'id'            => '_checkbox[' . $variation->ID . ']', 
        'label'         => __('My Checkbox Field', 'woocommerce' ), 
        'description'   => __( 'Check me!', 'woocommerce' ),
        'value'         => get_post_meta( $variation->ID, '_checkbox', true ), 
        )
    );
    // Hidden field
    woocommerce_wp_hidden_input(
    array( 
        'id'    => '_hidden_field[' . $variation->ID . ']', 
        'value' => 'hidden_value'
        )
    );
}
/**
 * Save new fields for variations
 *
*/
function save_variation_settings_fields( $post_id ) {
    // Text Field
    $text_field = $_POST['_text_field'][ $post_id ];
    if( ! empty( $text_field ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_text_field', esc_attr( $text_field ) );
    }

    // Number Field
    $number_field = $_POST['_number_field'][ $post_id ];
    if( ! empty( $number_field ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_number_field', esc_attr( $number_field ) );
    }
    // Textarea
    $textarea = $_POST['_textarea'][ $post_id ];
    if( ! empty( $textarea ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_textarea', esc_attr( $textarea ) );
    }

    // Select
    $select = $_POST['_select'][ $post_id ];
    if( ! empty( $select ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_select', esc_attr( $select ) );
    }

    // Checkbox
    $checkbox = isset( $_POST['_checkbox'][ $post_id ] ) ? 'yes' : 'no';
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_checkbox', $checkbox );

    // Hidden field
    $hidden = $_POST['_hidden_field'][ $post_id ];
    if( ! empty( $hidden ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_hidden_field', esc_attr( $hidden ) );
    }
}
?>
```

**To get those values on the frontend we just need to use the popular get_post_meta() function.**

Reference  article at here:

http://www.remicorson.com/woocommerce-custom-fields-for-variations/

Comment: That just explains how to add variable products. It says nothing about adding custom fields to product variations and displaying them in the Additional Information tab.

Comment: @Jeppe Bech, Sorry i misunderstood your question. I just modified answer according to your needs.

Comment: If I add that code to my theme's functions.php the website becomes unavailable. Is there something wrong with the code or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Question updated as it seemed perhaps not to be clear enough what I wanted to accomplish.

Comment: @AtifTariq Thanks for updating your answer to include the code.

Comment: Removing the initial `<?php` tag from the above code makes the custom fileds for variations work, but only for backend. I still need a way to display those value in frontend in the Aditional Information tab.

Comment: To get those values on the frontend you just need to use the popular get_post_meta() function.

Comment: Right. Can you provide an example of how to use `get_post_meta()` to get the value in the Additional Information tab?

Comment: ```echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my-field-slug', true );```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a first attempt. There's not a lot to go on in the attributes table, but when an attribute dropdown is changed, it will find the attribute in the additional information tab (where it is listed in default WooCommerce) and change the text to match the label in the dropdown. A problem occurs when the customer switches back to the empty "choose" option, so you'd need to expand this to somehow account for that.

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {

    $( ".variations_form" ).on( 'change', '.variations select', function() {
        id = $(this).attr('id');
        attribute = toTitleCase( $(this).attr('id').replace("pa_", "") );
        selected = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
        $('#tab-additional_information').find('.shop_attributes th:contains('+attribute+')').next('td').text(selected);
    });

    function toTitleCase(str){
        return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();});
    }
});
```

Save the above as `somescript.js` in your theme's folder. Then add the following to `functions.php` to properly enqueue the script.

```
/**
 * Proper way to enqueue scripts and styles
 */
function theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/somescript.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
```

Comment: Where does that code go? I tried puting it at the end of my theme's functions.php, but that caused the site to go blank (server error 500).

Comment: It's a javascript, so no it doesn't belong in `functions.php`. You need to save it as a `something.js` file and use [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) from your `functions.php` to load it.

Comment: OK, tried it, but it doesn't work. Somehow it screws up the product image sizes though.

Comment: Product images size appear to be ok now, so I guess it had nothing to do with that script anyway, some other random flaw, I suppose. Script still not working though.